# Remove script and link tags from string

Tags: c#, html, string

I am trying to remove `script` and `link` tags from a string. Below is what I got till now.

**Code**

```
rawHtml = rawHtml.Remove(rawHtml.IndexOf("<script"), (rawHtml.LastIndexOf("</script>") - 
          rawHtml.IndexOf("<script")) + 5);

rawHtml = rawHtml.Remove(rawHtml.IndexOf("<link"), (rawHtml.LastIndexOf("/>") - 
          rawHtml.IndexOf("<link")) + 3);
```

Is there better way without manually writing the numbers ?

Comment: If you are trying to prevent xss attacks, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064159/prevent-cross-site-scripting-attack-in-asp-net

Comment: @Sycraw , No, I just want html string without `script` and `link` tags , actually I will export this html to excel.

Comment: ok... for now the only alternative that I get is (if it's a well-formed HTML) to convert it to an xmldocument and remove the tags with xpath:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611/removing-nodes-from-an-xmldocument

Don't know for the performance, but if rawhtml is just a string, working with strings it's really heavy because they're value types and maybe this solution could improve the performance

Answer (score 2):

This will remove all contents between script, link and style tags, then remove the html tags (but keep the content) from the rest.

NOTE: Following @yelliver improvement on my previous answer, have incorporated that (having upvoted) and addressed your point about links.

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper method to strip html tags from html
/// </summary>
/// <param name="htmlText">raw html</param>
/// <returns>string without html tags</returns>
public string StripHTML(string hTMLText)
{
    // Remove script and style tags
    Regex rRemScript = new Regex(@"<(script|style)[^>]*>[\s\S]*?</\1>");
    hTMLText = rRemScript.Replace(hTMLText, "");

    // Remove link tags AND CONTENTS
    Regex rRemLink = new Regex(@"<link[\s\S]*?/>");
    hTMLText = rRemLink.Replace(hTMLText, "");

    // Strip other html tags (leaving contents)
    Regex reg = new Regex("<[^>]+>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return reg.Replace(hTMLText, "");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't remove the `link` tags , link tag starts with `<link` and ends with `/>`

Comment: @stom - doh! good point. It must keep the content then. I tried it on a site and it did strip the link tags.

Answer (score 2):

Using backreferences, I improve @HockeyJ answer:
Instead of:

```
Regex rRemScript = new Regex(@"<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?</script>");
hTMLText = rRemScript.Replace(hTMLText, "");

// Remove link content
Regex rRemLink = new Regex(@"<link[^>]*>[\s\S]*?</link>");
hTMLText = rRemLink.Replace(hTMLText, "");

// Remove style content
Regex rRemStyle = new Regex(@"<style[^>]*>[\s\S]*?</style>");
hTMLText = rRemStyle.Replace(hTMLText, "");
```

Just use:

```
Regex rRemScript = new Regex(@"<(script|link|style)[^>]*>[\s\S]*?</\1>");
hTMLText = rRemScript.Replace(hTMLText, "");
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't remove the `link` tags , link tag starts with `<link` and ends with `/>`